# Call the same function for two types of events

Tags: jquery

The code calculates the total price of a list of services. I have an input tag to for each service. When the price of a service is modified, the total price is calculated.

```
$(document).on('change key paste keyup', '[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="unitPrice"]', function() {

  //here the code to calculate the total price
}
```

Now I would like to calculate also the total when one of the services is remove from the list. How can I do that reusing the code to calculate the total price?

NOTE: of course, next to each service I have a link with a class "remove-service".

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to manually start that logic when they are removed.  Currently until Observers are more broadly implemented, there isn't a great way of detecting that an element has been added/removed from the DOM and as a result do something.  This is, of course, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

Give your function a name.  Then you can call it.  Anonymous functions are useful only when you need to pass it as an argument only once.

Example:

```
function updatePrices() {
  //here the code to calculate the total price
}


$(document).on('change key paste keyup', '[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="unitPrice"]', updatePrices);

$(document).on('click', 'a.remove-service', updatePrices);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var calculateTotalPrice = function() {
    //calculator algorithm here
}

$(document).on('change key paste keyup', '[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="unitPrice"]', calculateTotalPrice);

$('a.remove-service-link').click(function(e) {
    // to prevent run the a href
    e.preventDefault();

    // your remove service code here

    // then call calculate function
    calculateTotalPrice();
});
```